# How user search can be done using NAME?

Tags: mysql

I am making user search based on Users first name and Users last name. So i want some search cases that should guide me and made me to make search engine to search and give efficient result...!!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: hey i didn't mean that you people write code for me i just want to know how user search can be implemented....what are the search cases which we can use for that...and is there any code that i can refer,,,thats it.
I write my code on my own...As i don't have to much experience so i just want some guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you mean but I guess you are looking for something like this...

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE First_Name LIKE '%John%' OR Last_Name LIKE '%Doe%'
```